# ClientWebSocket.ConnectAsync closing immediately

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm implementing a small `ClientWebSocket` to send messages to the `IPAddress.Loopback` address of the computer so that a browser utility page can pick them up. however as soon as I connect, the client is immediately closed without message, reason, or exception.

```
ClientWebSocket cws;
Uri address = new Uri("ws://" + IPAddress.Loopback.ToString() + ":80/"

async void Start(){
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
        SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    using (cws = new ClientWebSocket()) {
        cws.Options.KeepAliveInterval = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);

        //Start response listener loop
        _ = Task.Run(() => async_ListenerLoop(receiveCancelTokenSrc.Token).ConfigureAwait(false));
        
        try {
            //Start the connection
            cws.ConnectAsync(address, sendCancelTokenSrc.Token);

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect.\n\r\n\r" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}


async Task async_ListenerLoop(CancellationToken cancelToken) {
    ArraySegment<byte> buffer = WebSocket.CreateServerBuffer(RECIEVE_BUFFER);
    List<byte> rawData = new List<byte>();

    try {
        while (state != WebSocketState.Closed && state != WebSocketState.Aborted && !cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
            if(state == WebSocketState.Connecting) {
                //Sometimes it waits 2-3 cycles, other times it closes immediately              
                await Task.Delay(500);
                continue;
            }

            WebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult = await cws.ReceiveAsync(buffer, cancelToken);

            if (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
                if (state == WebSocketState.CloseReceived && receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close) {
                    sendCancelTokenSrc.Cancel();

                    await cws.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Acknowledge Close frame", CancellationToken.None);
                    //The socket state changes to closed at this point
                }

                if (state == WebSocketState.Open) {
                    if (receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text) {
                        rawData.AddRange(buffer.Array);
                            
                        if (receiveResult.EndOfMessage) {
                            string strData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rawData.ToArray(), 0, rawData.Count);
                            ProcessData(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestDigest>(strData));
                            rawData.Clear();
                        }

                    } else if (receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Binary) {
                        rawData.AddRange(buffer.Array);

                        if (receiveResult.EndOfMessage) {
                            ProcessData(rawData.ToArray());
                            rawData.Clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Descripion is always null
        MessageBox.Show("Connection was closed because '"+cws.CloseStatusDescription+"'");

        } catch (OperationCanceledException ex) {
            // normal upon task/token cancellation, disregard
            MessageBox.Show("Connection to server cancelled.\n\r\n\r" + ex.Message);

        } catch (JsonReaderException ex) {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to read incoming message.\n\r\n\r" + ex.Message);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable recieve incoming message.\n\r\n\r" + ex.Message);

        } finally {
            sendCancelTokenSrc.Cancel();
            AbortConnection();
        }
    }
    
void AbortConnection() {
    // don't leave the socket in any potentially connected state
    if (state != WebSocketState.Closed) {
        cws.Abort();
    }
    cws.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be other problems with your code (wiring up sockets and clients takes a bit of messing about before you get it right) but there are two glaring problems:

You need to await the result of `ConnectAsync(...)`, to stop the code of `Start()` continuing synchronously without it:

```cs
await cws.ConnectAsync(address, sendCancelTokenSrc.Token);
```

And you need to make sure that `cws` does not get disposed until you've finished with it. The `using(cws) { ... }` block will dispose `cws` as soon as the code leaves the squiggly braces (which happens straight away currently), even though your listener is still running, and needs it to remain alive.

You can either do that by keeping the code within the `using` block by awaiting an asynchronous result (such as *hint!* a final result from your listener) - or by not using `using` at all and manually disposing `cws` yourself at the right time.

Also make sure to only start your listener after the connection call has completed, to ensure `cws` is in a good state.

Something like this:

```cs
using(cws = new ClientWebSocket())
{
    await cws.ConnectAsync(...);
    await DoSomeListeningForABit();
} //cws gets implicitly disposed here
```

And... your listener will doubtlessly require more work too, but the above will get you past your immediate problem (hopefully!)

Comment: I removed the using and separated the listening and connecting into their own methods so that I can better control when to listen to an incoming request and when to connect to another service and finally started getting error messages that I can now hunt down. (It doesn't help that on the drive home I realized that while my listener is listening, the fundamental flaw in the implementation is that it'll never receive a message unless it's connected to another first...)

Comment: Good stuff, progress!